# Google App Script: DriveApp.getFolderById not working on time-driven trigger?

Tags: google-apps-script

```
function backup(folder="1FrDJm--FLGsw8gg5M1pHRcw-T70q8sxF"){
  var ss =  SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  let toFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folder);
  DriveApp.getFileById(ss.copy(ss.getName()).getId()).moveTo(toFolder);

  ss.rename("backup（" + getNextSunday() + "）")
}
```

I set the code above to trigger every Monday morning to backup the current file in a backup folder and then rename the current file. I can manually run this function without any problem, but it returns this error while executed by the time-drive trigger.

> ```
> Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property getFolderById on object DriveApp.
>     at backup(Code:3:27)
> ```

Anyone knows why?

Comment: This seems to be more likely a *specific issue* on Apps Script when a function with a [default function parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) _(e.g folder="1FrDJm--FLGsw8gg5M1pHRcw-T70q8sxF")_ gets used in a time-based trigger. I did a test run on the `backup` function & logged the `folder` parameter in a time-based trigger & returned this [value](https://imgur.com/a/woXhirp) *vs* when the function gets manually run from the Apps Script editor as [seen here](https://imgur.com/a/uuNbk64).

Comment: @SputnikDrunk2 In the current stage, when the function is run by the time-driven trigger, the event object is given to the 1st argument. Although it seems that this is not written in the document of [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/ref-search-terms), it seems that this is written in the document of [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#time-driven_events).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the current stage, when the function is run by the time-driven trigger, the event object is given to the 1st argument. I thought that this is the reason for your current issue.

So, when your function is run by the time-driven trigger, `folder` of `function backup(folder="1FrDJm--FLGsw8gg5M1pHRcw-T70q8sxF"){` is as follows.

```json
{
  "triggerUid":"###",
  ,
  ,
  ,
}
```

By this, `folder` is not `"1FrDJm--FLGsw8gg5M1pHRcw-T70q8sxF"`. So, your error occurs.

In order to avoid this issue, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
function backup(folder="1FrDJm--FLGsw8gg5M1pHRcw-T70q8sxF"){
```

#### To:

```
function backup(folder) {
  if (typeof folder == "object") {
    folder = "1FrDJm--FLGsw8gg5M1pHRcw-T70q8sxF";
  }
```

or, as a simple modification, how about the following modification?

```
function backup(eventObj, folder="1FrDJm--FLGsw8gg5M1pHRcw-T70q8sxF") {
```

#### Reference:

- [Time-driven events](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#time-driven_events)

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, would you mind elaborating on why not just add the folder as a constant value within the function but instead pass it as an argument? I tried my suggestion and it worked just fine. But based on your answer, I believe you did it that way because of something I fail to understand. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Matias CG About `would you mind elaborating on why not just add the folder as a constant value within the function but instead pass it as an argument?`, I guessed that from your script, you might have wanted to use the function of `backup` with not only the trigger but also calling from other function. So, I proposed the modified script including the OP's direction by showing the clear reason for your current issue. If this was not your wanted explanation, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your time-driven trigger is not working properly because the variable that is being passed as an argument in the function is not being recognized by the script. Try this:

```
function backup(){
 const folder = "1FrDJm--FLGsw8gg5M1pHRcw-T70q8sxF";
 const ss =  SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 let toFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folder);
 DriveApp.getFileById(ss.copy(ss.getName()).getId()).moveTo(toFolder);

 ss.rename("backup（" + getNextSunday() + "）")
}
```